# Java: Saving variables issue

Tags: java

I am trying make it so every time the program loops it saves into a file. Currently I have this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class writing {



    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        String FileName = input.next();
        String x = input.next();

        for(int i=0; i<'x'; i++){

            System.out.println("Question");
            String MainQ = input1.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Option 1:  ");
            String Op1 = input1.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Option 2:  ");
            String Op2 = input1.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Option 3:  ");
            String Op3 = input1.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Correct Answer (Option Number:)  " );
            String An1 = input1.next();

            System.out.println("Quesiton 1:"+ MainQ);
            System.out.println(""+ Op1);
            System.out.println(""+ Op2);
            System.out.println(""+ Op3);
            String UAn1 = input1.next();
            if (UAn1 == An1){
                System.out.println("Incorrect");    
                System.out.println("Answer is:  " + An1);
            }else{  
                System.out.println("Correct");

            }

            try{

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(FileName + ".txt");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                pw.println(MainQ);
                pw.println(Op1);
                pw.println(Op2);
                pw.println(Op3);
                pw.println(An1);

                pw.close();

            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

There isn't an error message, sorry for the bad question. I would like for every time the program loops for the text file to come out like this:

```
(Question 1) Question Example 
(Option 1) Option Example .... 

(Question 2) Question Example 
(Option 1) Option Example
```

... and so on. But the way it is working now it only records the last input

Coming out like this: 
(Imagine I use 3 for the third question and option number)

```
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Include any exceptions/error messages.

Comment: There isnt an error message, sorry for the bad question.

I would like for every time the program loops for the text file to come out like this:

(Question 1) *Question Example*
(Option 1) *Option Example*
.... 

(Question 2) *Question Example*
(Option 1) *Option Example*

and so on. But the way it is working now it only records the last input.

Comment: Well, if `filename` is always the same variable, the same file will always be created. What to do?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Format your code for better readability.

Comment: It's idiomatic for Java to have capitalized CamelCase class names and non capitalized variables. So the class should be `Writing` and `String FileName` should be `fileName`.

Comment: [Do **not** compare Strings with `==`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

As you are creating the `FileWriter` inside the for loop it is always overwriting the content, therefore keeping apparently only the last content. You should move the lines

```
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(FileName + ".txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
```

before the `for` statement (and try/catch block accoringly).

Answer (score 1):

Open the `FileWriter` in append mode, otherwise it will just overwrite your text file instead of appending to it. See the [`FileWriter constructor documentation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.lang.String-boolean-).

Also, as others have pointed out, `camelCase` is the convention for variable names in Java, not `PascalCase`, and you [must not compare strings with `==` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).